# Java save data for sometime for different instances of service

Tags: java, database, caching, queue, storage

I want to save pin for incoming requests to a service for 3 mins and then delete it. 
What would be the best approach to do so? Save the data in database which will be queried for 3 mins  OR use a queue or cache?

The number of incoming requests will be 100 000 per second.

Comment: Check out Guavas LoadingCache for something like this, you can set an expiry time.
It all depends on your application

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But will use of LoadCache result into memory consumption in my application wherein the number of incoming requests is too huge?

Comment: LoadingCache or hazelCacheInstance which is better

Comment: It will. It all depends on how responsive you want your application to be. Honestly, storing 100 000 items in a database per second which last for 3 minutes would result in 6 million writes per minute, and that doesn't even account for the deletions.
If something is only alive for 3 minutes, you should consider why you want to persist it to a database. Do you really need it to be persisted if the application goes down seeing as it has such a short lifetime